# Problems with getting text from UIAlertView textfield

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertview, textfield

In my application I want a alert with a textfield. After clicking on "Done" I want to save the textfield input in a String. After clicking on "Cancel" I want only to close the alert. I've created my alert like this:

```
    var alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Enter Input"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Done")
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    alert.show()

    let textField = alert.textFieldAtIndex(0)
    textField!.placeholder = "Enter an Item"
    println(textField!.text)
```

The alert looks like this:

[image: My alert]

I want to know how to get the text from the textfield, and how to create events for the "Done" button and the "Cancel" button.

Comment: You need to implement the appropriate `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods (and set the `delegate` property of the alert view).

Comment: can someone give me an example with this "UIAlerrViewDelegate" ?

Comment: Please do a [little searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uialertview+swift).

Comment: I searched about this topic, now I've a way to check which button was pressed. But I haven't found a running solution for getting the text from the textfield. So please help me about this!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may go with UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView.

I've already implemented and tested too using UIAlertController for what you actually want. Please try the following code

```
    var tField: UITextField!

    func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        print("generating the TextField")
        textField.placeholder = "Enter an item"
        tField = textField
    }

    func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
    {
        print("Cancelled !!")
    }

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Input", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextField)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler:handleCancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        print("Done !!")

        print("Item : \(self.tField.text)")
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm searching for.

Comment: Thanks for this.. :)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Glad that it helped you!

Comment: Nice Code exactly looking for this..:)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to implement the UIAlertViewDelegate's

```
optional func alertView(_ alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
```

Answer (score 2):

For **SWIFT 3**

```
@IBAction func ForgotPassword(_ sender: Any) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email?", message: "Please input your email:", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (_) in
        if let field = alertController.textFields![0] as? UITextField {

            // store and use entered data

        } else {

            print("please enter email id")
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
    }

    alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I hope it will help someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 8+ you should use UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView. To support iOS 7 you should implement (UIAlertViewDelegate):

```
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    //...
    let textField = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)
}
```