# Getting nothing from UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield

In the below code I have a button which will prompt user to enter my admin passphrase. If I click Ok button it should be able to set message to **inputTextField** and display the message

[image]

```
var inputTextField: UITextField?

@IBAction func logOutButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionController = UIAlertController(title: "Log out", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    actionController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Admin passphrase"
        textField.secureTextEntry = true

        self.inputTextField = textField

    }

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){UIAlertAction in

        if self.inputTextField != nil{
            print(self.inputTextField)
        }else{
            print("Nothing")
        }

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){UIAlertAction in
        print("Test: Log out action cancelled")
    }



    actionController.addAction(okAction)
    actionController.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This is what I get from the console after entering "admin" and click ok

**Console message:
Optional(<_UIAlertControllerTextField: 0x7fc90bc58d00; frame = (4 4; 229 16); text = 'admin'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = ; layer = >)**

Everything works fine until I change my the following to

```
var inputTextField: String?

self.inputTextField = textField.text
```

and result:
**Optional("")**

I'm certain that something must have sent to inputTextField but I can't get it out, any idea?

Comment: If you want to get the value. Why don't you just declare a string variable to store the input. Just initiate the variable to empty string first `var ans:String = ""` and store the input. Then just check is the `ans == ""` or it is filled with user input

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work that way

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30139623/3734028

Comment: Try mine answer too :) i just tried on my apps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also access the textField of UIAlertController by this way :

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "Type the msg", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alertView.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
    textField.placeholder = "Admin passphrase"
    textField.secureTextEntry = true
}

let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction) -> Void in

    let val = (alertView.textFields![0] as UITextField).text! as String
    if val == "" {
        print("nothing")
    } else {
        print(val)
    }
}
alertView.addAction(alertAction)

presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this inside the OK button function.

```
//  myText will be the first textField in alert controller, store its text into ans
let myText = actionController.textFields![0] 
let ans = myText.text
if ans != ""{
    print(ans)
}else{
    print("Nothing")
}
```

This will get the first textField inside your alertController, and then you just store the it in any variable and do you condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get text from the prombt alertview. Use following code.

```
        let actionController = UIAlertController(title: "Log out", message: "Are you sure you want to log out?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            actionController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Admin passphrase"
            textField.secureTextEntry = true

            //self.inputTextField = textField // remove

        }

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){UIAlertAction in

            if self.inputTextField != nil{
                let textField:UITextField = (actionController.textFields?[0])!;
                self.inputTextField.text = textField.text;
                 NSLog("%@",textField.text!)
            }else{
                print("Nothing")
            }

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){UIAlertAction in
            print("Test: Log out action cancelled")
        }

        actionController.addAction(okAction)
        actionController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I got an error Value of type 'String?' has no member 'text'

Comment: **Replace this code**
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { UIAlertAction in
            let textField:UITextField = (actionController.textFields?[0])!;
            NSLog("%@",textField.text!)
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: Have created or initialized the inputTextField in storyboard?