# Swift: UITextField is not being recognized

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want the user to press a button, and then for them to be able to see an alert where they can enter an input (to set a price for a service). The other logic involves saving data to a database, which is not really relevant to my problem.

I am using the following example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30139623/2411290

It definitely works, in that it shows the alert correctly, but once I include

```
print("Amount: \(self.tField.text)")
```

"self.tField.text" is not recognized. The specific error I get is:

> value of type 'testVC' has no member 'tField'

```
@IBAction func setAmount(_ sender: Any) {

    var tField: UITextField!


    func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        print("generating textField")
        textField.placeholder = "Enter amount"
        tField = textField

    }

    func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
    {
        print("Cancelled")
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Set price of service", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: configurationTextField)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:handleCancel))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in
        print("Done !!")

    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
        print("Amount: \(self.tField.text)") // Error here


    })

    //// other logic for app
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tField` is a local variable inside your `setAmount` function. It is not a property of the class.

Change:

```
self.tField.text
```

to:

```
tField.text
```

That will allow you to access the local variable.

But the real question is why are you creating a local variable of `UITextField` inside this function? Why are you printing its text when the text field isn't used anywhere?

Most likely you should be accessing the alert's text field inside the action handler for the "Done" button. There's no need to do anything inside the completion block of presenting the alert.

```
@IBAction func setAmount(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Set price of service", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
        print("generating textField")
        textField.placeholder = "Enter amount"
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        print("Cancelled")
    })

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { (action) in
        print("Done !!")
        if let textField = alert.textFields?.first {
            print("Amount: \(textField.text)")
        }
    })

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, so thank you. I created a few global variables, price and tField (UITextField). I can't really handle all of the logic inside the "Done" handler, I need to store the value of the price, because I am inputting 5-6 values at one time into my Firebase database outside of the alert.

Comment: There's no need to store text fields as globals.

Comment: I am adding self.price = self.tField.text! inside of my "done" handler. It doesn't seem like it saves the value, when I try to save it to my DB (after the alert). I'm guessing that is not the correct way to go about this. Let me try your exact implementation.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that when you present an alert your current ViewController is the alert viewController... And in your alert there is no variable tField.

On the exampled you quoted the alert was presented only after the print with tField's value. That why that worked there and doesn't work in your case.